# pushing values to stack class using linked list struct c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, stack

So I am implementing a stack class using linked lists and I need to push a string into the stack but the stack can only hold ints. I am trying to split the string into ints and push each one of them into the stack but no dice.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Stack {
public: 
    Stack() { 
        top = NULL;
        count = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

    void push(int numberToPush) {
        //create a new linkedlistnode assing its value to number to push
        //and add it to the underlying linkedlist structure
        LinkedListNode *n = new LinkedListNode;
        n -> val = numberToPush;
        n -> next = top;
        top = n;
        size++;
    }

    int pop() {
        //returns value of the node at the top of the stack and removes the node
        if(isEmpty()) {
            cout << "stack is empty pop" << endl; 
            return -1;
        }

        LinkedListNode *temp = top;
        top = temp -> next;
        return temp -> val;
    }

    int peek() {
        //returns the value of the node at the top of the stack, but does not remove the node
        if(isEmpty()) {
            cout << "stack is empty" << endl; 
            return -1;
        }

        return top -> val;
    }

    void display() {
        LinkedListNode *n = top;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout<< top->val << ", ";
            top=top->next;  
        }
    }
    bool isEmpty() {
        return top == NULL;
    }

private:
struct LinkedListNode {
        int val;
        LinkedListNode *next;

};

    LinkedListNode* top;
    int count; 
    int size;
};

int main() {
    string Input; 

    cout << "enter a word or phrase: ";
    cin >> Input;

    Stack s;

    for(int i = 0; i < Input.length(); i++)
        s.push(Input[i]);

    s.display();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Change your class so the stack holds strings?

Comment: Use the "template" keyword to parameterize the class on the type.

Comment: Please create a clear problem statement, expected and actual results, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: You push `Input.size()` copies of `atoi(Input.c_str())` into your stack. If `Input` was `123`, your stack is now `{123, 123, 123}`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: no I need it to be {1, 2, 3}

Answer (score -1):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
      a = atoi(Input.c_str());
      s.push(a);
 }
```

I don't think this code is doing what you think it is doing. atoi() converts a string to an int, i.e. "76" becomes 76. You seem to be wanting the ASCII value of each character in the string, for which the code would look more like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
      a = (int)Input[i];
      s.push(a);
 }
```

Note that this creates n different elements in the Stack, one for each character in the string. If you need to add things besides integers to your Stack, you should create a template for your class rather than do conversions back and forth like this.

Comment: integers will do for this one